# Utilizar una variable fuera del try and catch

Tags: c#

Hola buenas andaba practicando un poco sobre el manejo de errores, llegando a este codigo :

```
       using System;


       namespace _11_Operadores
       {
       class Program
       {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        int resultado;

        Console.WriteLine(" Ingrese un numero ");
        string num = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(" Ingrese un segundo numero ");
        string num2 = Console.ReadLine();

        try
        {

            int numP = int.Parse(num);
            int numP2 = int.Parse(num2);

        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(" No puede contener campos vacios ");

        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(" El valor ingresado debe ser numerico ");

        }
        catch (OverflowException)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(" El valor ingresado es muy grande o muy pequeño ");

        }

        resultado = numP + numP2;

        Console.WriteLine(" El resultado es : " + resultado);
        Console.Read();


      }
   }
}
```

El tema que esos 2 numeros los quiero sumar si hago el parse fuera del try perfecto si puedo pero una ves lo pongo dentro el try ya no puedo hacer la suma de estas dos variables, alguna solución o tip que me pueda servir para un futuro, muchas gracias.

Comment: si, simplemente definilos afuera del try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tambien puedes meterlo todo dentro del bloque try, talque asi

```
using System;
       namespace _11_Operadores
       {
       class Program
       {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        int resultado;


        try
        {        
            Console.WriteLine(" Ingrese un numero ");
            string num = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(" Ingrese un segundo numero ");
            string num2 = Console.ReadLine();
            int numP= int.Parse(num);
            int numP2 = int.Parse(num2);

        resultado = numP + numP2;

        Console.WriteLine(" El resultado es : " + resultado);
        Console.Read();


        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(" No puede contener campos vacios ");

        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(" El valor ingresado debe ser numerico ");

        }
        catch (OverflowException)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(" El valor ingresado es muy grande o muy pequeño ");

        }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: No necesitas crear otra respuesta. Simplemente edita la que tenías antes.

Answer (score 3):

Lo que puedes hacer es declarar numP y numP2 fuera del try asi:

```
using System;
       namespace _11_Operadores
       {
       class Program
       {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        int resultado;

        Console.WriteLine(" Ingrese un numero ");
        string num = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(" Ingrese un segundo numero ");
        string num2 = Console.ReadLine();

        int numP;
        int numP2;

        try
        {
            numP= int.Parse(num);
            numP2 = int.Parse(num2);
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(" No puede contener campos vacios ");

        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(" El valor ingresado debe ser numerico ");

        }
        catch (OverflowException)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(" El valor ingresado es muy grande o muy pequeño ");

        }

        resultado = numP + numP2;

        Console.WriteLine(" El resultado es : " + resultado);
        Console.Read();


      }
   }
}
```

Si declaras una variable dentro del bloque try solo sera visible dentro de ese bloque

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda aun que por alguna razón me sigue dando error, lo solucione cuando elimine los exeption, pero necesito esos exeption xD

Comment: @DragonsDTi mostra el error que te da y te ayudamos a resolverlo como corresponde.. hace otra pregunta sobre eso..